# Can't get WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole("domain\\groupname") to work

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory

I have a WPF app that needs to determine if the current user is a member of an AD group.

I created AD group "TestGroup" in the following location in the AD "tree":

Apps/Shared/Groups/TestGroup

I'm testing the app under VS 2010, running as my domain login, which is a member of TestGroup (and yes, I've logged-off/on since I added myself to that group).

My domain name is ABC.

I first get the WindowsPrincipal by doing:

if (!Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(GetWindowsIdentity());

(which, BTW, always invokes GetWindowsIdentity()... could that be the problem?)

Then I do:

```
_windowsPrincipal.IsInRole(@"ABC\TestGroup")
```

... which always returns false.

Am I passing the correct string to IsInRole?  Or do I need to specify the full path of the AD "tree", like:  @"ABC\Apps\Shared\Groups\TestGroup" (I've tried just about every permutation). Or could this problem be caused by running in debug under VS?

Or ????

Thanks!

DadCat

Comment: What does your 'GetWindowsIdentity()' method do? WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole() seems to work fine for me with either just 'rolename' or 'domain\rolename' (I created my WindowsPrincipal with 'new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())')

Comment: It **appears** that the problem is not in the code. Instead, I had not _rebooted_ since I added myself to the group. I had **thought** that a _logoff/logon_ was all that was needed, but apparently not. Did something change in Win8?

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment: It appears that the problem is not in the code. Instead, I had not rebooted since I added myself to the group. I had thought that a logoff/logon ("sign off/on") was all that was needed, but apparently a full reboot is necessary. Maybe this is a new "feature" of Win8.